# How to display a flash message in a template

Tags: plugin-development, templating, error-message

I have a plugin that accepts a form post. I need to return a notice or error, plus the original data. Starting with the notice/error first, I have tried this:

```
if (craft()->broadbean_jobs->createJob())
{
    craft()->userSession->setNotice(Craft::t('Job created.'));
}
else
{
    craft()->userSession->setError(Craft::t('Unable to create job.'));
}

$this->redirectToPostedUrl();
```

How can I display the notice or error in my template?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `setFlash` function in the `userSession` Service like this:

In your Controller:

```
craft()->userSession->setFlash('yourVariable', "Something happened yo!");
```

In your template (that the user gets redirected to):

```
{% set message = craft.session.getFlash('yourVariable') %}
```

After that just run an if-statement to see if the message is set or not.

EDIT:
In Craft 3 controller:

```
Craft::$app->session->setFlash('yourVariable', "Something happened yo!");
```

In template:

```
{% set message = craft.app.session.getFlash('yourVariable') %}
{% if message|length > 0 %}
    {{message}}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You can still use `setNotice` and `setError` and display flashes with `getFlash('notice')` and `getFlash('error')` respectively