# Confirm Password on Set Password Form

Tags: plugin-development, events

Is there a way to send errors back to the set password form?

I am listening to the `users.onBeforeSetPassword` event in which I want to confirm that the string in a confirm password field is the same as in the newPassword field.

```
craft()->on('users.onBeforeSetPassword', function(Event $event) {
       // Only do anything if it is a front end submission
       if(craft()->request->isSiteRequest())
       {
           $newPassword = craft()->request->getPost('newPassword');
           $passwordConfirm = craft()->request->getPost('passwordConfirm');
           if(isset($passwordConfirm) && strcmp($newPassword, $passwordConfirm) !== 0)
           {
               $event->params['user']->addErrors(array('newPassword' => Craft::t('Passwords do not match')));
               $event->performAction = false;
           }
       }
   });
  }
}
```

This does prevent the user from resetting their password but doesn't send a error message back to the template.  How can I pass a variable back to the template so I can show the user their error?

Comment: This is only possible when you copy and paste the controller action in your custom controller. It takes usually about 2-3 minutes to do this. If you don't want this for any reasons you can include Javascript after setting your  `performAction` and include the html by yourself. You just have to append an unsorted list with the message.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `craft()->userSession->setFlash('your message here');` functionality.

How it works is explained in [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15152/6991) or [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4602/6991) answer for example but it boils down to setting the message in your event handler and then checking in your template if there's a message and if there's one, display it.